# variable char* wont free up?

Tags: c, malloc, free

so i'm coding a function that takes a line from a file and print it, the problem is i can't free up the char* variable here's the code

```
int main()
{
    char *line; 
    int fd;

    fd = open("text.txt", O_RDONLY);
    int ret = 0;
        while (ret < 3)
        {
            get_next_line(fd, &line);
            printf("%s\n", line);
            free(line);
            ret++;
        }

}
```

the line variable it get allocated in the get_next_line function with the function

```
strdup("");
```

here is the get_next_line func

```
int get_next_line(int fd, char **line)
{
    char *buff;
    int bwr;
    char *ptr;
    int bol;
    static char *rem;


    bol = 1; 
    buff = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (BUFFER_SIZE + 1));
    if(rem)
    {
        *line = ft_strdup(rem);
        printf("---1ST---%s\n", rem);
        free(rem);
        printf("---2ND---%s\n", rem);
    }
    else
        *line = ft_strdup("");
    while (bol && (bwr = read(fd, buff, BUFFER_SIZE)))
    {
        buff[bwr] = '\0';
        if ((ptr = ft_strchr(buff, '\n')))
        {
            rem = ft_strdup(ptr + 1);
            *ptr = '\0'; 
            bol = 0;
        }
        *line = ft_strjoin(*line ,buff);
    }
        return(0);
}
```

so i don't know why it won't free up the **line**

PS: i'm using lldb to check the memory blocks, Thanks.

Comment: Suggestion: turn on your compiler warning to the maximum. Mind them.

Comment: Show code for `get_next_line`

Comment: i edited the post

Comment: Just because you call `free`, the contents of the memory won't be magically erased from the physical cells. Nor will `free` change the address of the pointer `rem`. So it still points at the same area as before, though accessing that area is no longer safe. Until some other part of the program decides to use this memory to store something else, the old data will remain there.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `rem` variable? It seems to do nothing useful but creating memory leaks.

Comment: Same with `ptr`. The `get_next_line` is just nonsense, it allocates random memory all over the place, then leaves it to leak.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah thanks, that is useful after calling ```free``` i use ```rem = NULL``` and it works, and rem is to store the rest of read function after the ```\n``` to store it and join it in the first in line after calling ```get_nex_line``` second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only gonna address the leaks in your program:
The first one is in this line:

> ```
> *line = ft_strjoin(*line ,buff);
> ```

What happens is that since the return value of your *ft_strjoin* is `*line`, the old memory address that `*line` used to point to is lost without being freed and now `*line` points to another memory address (the one that holds `*line + buff`).

You have two ways to correct this problem:

The first one is to do something like this:

```
char *to_free = *line;
*line = ft_strjoin(*line, buff);
free(to_free);
```

This will make *to_free* point the same memory address that `*line` points to before being changed by the call to `ft_strjoin`.
The other way (the better one in my opinion), is to implement `ft_strjoin` that takes a 3d argument `int n` for example, if `n = 1` you free the first argument of `ft_strjoin`, if `n = 2` you free the 2nd argument, if `n = 3` you free both (Be careful on where you free them inside your function).

> ```
> if (rem)
> ```

could return true even if you free it because you didn't do a `rem = NULL` explicitly afterwards (You're also calling `printf` to print `rem` after your free `rem`.

The last problem is that you're not freeing `buff` anywhere. You should free it before exiting your `get_next_line`.